# fatal error : use of undeclared identifier 'ConstIter'

Tags: c++

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        vector<int> result;
        if(nums.empty()){
            cout<<"Array is empty"<<endl;
        }else{
            for(int i=0;i<nums.size();i++){
//                 for(int j=0;j<nums.size();j++){
//                     if(i!=j && nums[i]+nums[j]==target ){

//                         result = {i,j};

//                     }

                int second=target-nums[i];
                if(find(nums.begin(),nums.end(),second)!=nums.end() && nums[i]!=second){
                    int j;
                    j=distance(ConstIter(nums.begin()),second);
                    result={i,j};


                }
            }
        }
        return result;

    }

};
```

**basically i want the index of the variable second and**
**to reduce run time complexity i had to remove one loop** 
*two sum problem on leetcode*

Comment: Change `ConstIter(nums.begin())` to `nums.cbegin()` if you want a constant iterator.

Comment: I'm curious where you think you've defined `ConstIter`. The compiler is telling you it's undefined, it's not defined in any of the code you've posted. You should at least say why you have used it and what you think it does.

Comment: To reduce execution time you can sort `nums` array, then use binary search instead of `find`. Or something more creative, such as searching for target sum from both ends of sorted array.

Comment: @Azeem i tried that and now i am getting no matching function for call to distance

Comment: @john I am a newbie and had no idea about defining ConstIter in code i just found this solution on internet, so could please explain me how to define it .BTW thanks john

Comment: @TanujChaniyari There's no definition of `ConstIter` that will make the code you wrote above work. You don't need a const iterator for distance, you can't make distance work with an integer (which is what you are trying to do), actually you don't need to use distance at all. See my answer below for what I think you are trying to do. You can't take code from the internet that does something different and expect it to work in your code, especially when you don't properly understand what the internet code does.

Comment: @TanujChaniyari: The type of `second` is not a match for `std::distance()` that's why you're getting an error. Here's an example solution for your reference: https://godbolt.org/z/B-BAG-. It's just a simple brute-force solution with quadratic time i.e. O(n^2) complexity. You can start from there and then move on towards a better algorithm e.g. linear time i.e. O(n).

Comment: @sklott: Sorting would be O(n log n) operation. It can be solved in O(n) using a lookup table.

Comment: In general, names that are defined in the C++ language or in the C++ standard library use lowercase letters. Names that have a mix of cases (`ConstIter`) come from somewhere else, so you have to figure out where it came from. It was probably defined somewhere else in the code that you copied.

Comment: @john Yeah got it know i will be aware before taking any code from internet , thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the code you're grasping for is this

```
if (nums[i] != second) {
    auto pos = find(nums.begin(), nums.end(), second);
    if (pos != nums.end())
        result = { i, pos - nums.begin() };
}
```

But don't think that using `find` instead of your own loop is going to improve the efficiency of your program. `find` just uses a loop internally, so it should be just the same.

Comment: so pos cant be added in a int vector right anyways thansk